# Question about convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I have that $v=v^+-v^-$, $v^+,v^-$ are the positive and the négative part of $v$ and i have this:

[image]

i dont understand why if $v_n\rightarrow v_0$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ then $v_n^+\rightarrow v_0^+$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{|v_n^+|^p\}$ is uniformly integrable and if $v_{n_k}\to v$ almost everywhere, then $v_{n_k}^+\to v^+$.